# Entity Framework Core 7 with Discriminator and child navigation property not populating property, but SQL requests data

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have three objects, there is not a FK relationship in the SQL database that links Order -> OrderDenial or OrderLine -> OrderLineDenial

```
    public partial class Order
    {
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<OrderLine> OrderLines { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<OrderDenial> Denials { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class OrderLine
    {
        public int OrderLineId { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<OrderLineDenial> Denials { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Denial
    {
        public int DenialId { get; set; }
        public int ReferenceId { get; set; }
        public string ReferenceType { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class OrderDenial : Denial
    {

    }

    public partial class OrderLineDenial : Denial
    {

    }
```

The configuration for these are as follows

```
public class OrderContext : DbContext
    {
        public OrderContext(DbContextOptions<OrderContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected OrderContext()
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<OrderDenial> OrderDenials { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<OrderLine> Claims { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<OrderLineDenial> OrderLineDenials { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new OrderConfiguration());
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new OrderLineConfiguration());
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new DenialConfiguration());
        }


        public partial class OrderConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Order>
        {
            public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Order> entity)
            {
                entity.ToTable(nameof(Order));

                entity.HasMany(e => e.Denials)
                  .WithOne()
                  .HasForeignKey(e => e.ReferenceId)
                  .HasPrincipalKey(e => e.OrderId);
            }
        }

        public partial class OrderLineConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<OrderLine>
        {
            public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<OrderLine> entity)
            {
                entity.ToTable(nameof(OrderLine));

                entity.HasMany(e => e.Denials)
                  .WithOne()
                  .HasForeignKey(e => e.ReferenceId)
                  .HasPrincipalKey(e => e.OrderLineId);
            }
        }

        public partial class DenialConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Denial>
        {
            public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Denial> entity)
            {
                entity.ToTable(nameof(Denial));

                entity.HasDiscriminator<string>(x => x.ReferenceType)
                  .HasValue<OrderDenial>(nameof(Order))
                  .HasValue<OrderLineDenial>(nameof(OrderLine));
            }
        }

    }
```

The linq query used to attempt to retrieve the data is as follows

```
            var query = _orderContext.Orders
              .Include(x => x.Denials)
              .Include(x => x.OrderLines).ThenInclude(x => x.Denials)
              .AsNoTracking().ToList();
```

So you can link Denials to multiple objects, by ReferenceId and ReferenceType, My example has Order 1 having one denial to to the order, and then order 2 has to OrderLines with one of the lines having a Denial linked to the OrderLine associated to it. The sql is using the discriminator correctly to look up with what should be associated to the correct items, and the result set that entity produces the correct amount of items, where I see the results I am looking for in it.

The resulting object always has an empty list for Denials.

The sql being produced from entities is

```
SELECT [o].[OrderId], [t].[DenialId], [t].[ReferenceId], [t].[ReferenceType], [t0].[OrderLineId], [t0].[OrderId], [t0].[DenialId], [t0].[ReferenceId], [t0].[ReferenceType]
FROM [Order] AS [o]
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [d].[DenialId], [d].[ReferenceId], [d].[ReferenceType]
    FROM [Denial] AS [d]
    WHERE [d].[ReferenceType] = N'Order'
) AS [t] ON [o].[OrderId] = [t].[ReferenceId]
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [o0].[OrderLineId], [o0].[OrderId], [t1].[DenialId], [t1].[ReferenceId], [t1].[ReferenceType]
    FROM [OrderLine] AS [o0]
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT [d0].[DenialId], [d0].[ReferenceId], [d0].[ReferenceType]
        FROM [Denial] AS [d0]
        WHERE [d0].[ReferenceType] = N'OrderLine'
    ) AS [t1] ON [o0].[OrderLineId] = [t1].[ReferenceId]
) AS [t0] ON [o].[OrderId] = [t0].[OrderId]
ORDER BY [o].[OrderId], [t].[DenialId], [t0].[OrderLineId]
```

I am expecting that the Denial List would be populated with items because I have records in the database that are being returned, but the list is always empty. Am i just attempting to do something not possible? It seems it should populate it according to the SQL being generated, but because it doesn't have a FK relationship entities ignores it?

Comment: I'm however getting a different SQL from your example, and everything works (both `Denials` collections are populated). Tried with the latest EFC 7.0.5, as well as 7.0.0. Something must be missing in your example, since the SQL is not even valid (there is no `[t1].[OrderID]` column), and also there must be an `ORDER BY` clause at the end, which is essential for correct materialization. Needs [mre].

Comment: I was able to get it to work, with a fresh database and just the concept outlined above. If i use that same simple concept and point it to my existing (more complex) database it still does not return the denials. The database is on compatibility 2012, but even doing that in my minimal example does not make a difference. I see no observable difference between the underlying tables that would make any difference. (made the changes above with minimal example for preservation)